# Pull Parsing local XML File in Android

Tags: android, xml, parsing, xmlpullparser

I'm trying to parse specific parts of a local XML using pull-parsing however, I'm not sure how I read those parts. I'm using the code:

```
package com.example.xmltest;


import java.io.IOException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.content.res.XmlResourceParser;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          TextView myXmlContent = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xml_tv);
          String stringXmlContent;

          stringXmlContent = getAllXML();
          myXmlContent.setText(stringXmlContent);

      }

      public String getAllXML(){

          Activity activity = this;
          String str = "";

          Resources res = activity.getResources();
          XmlResourceParser xpp = res.getXml(R.xml.ensaheehint);

          try {
              xpp.next();
              int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
              System.out.println("eventType : " + eventType);
              while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
              {
                   if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT){
                       str += "nXML Parsing Starting...n";
                   }
                   else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG)
                   {

                       eventType = xpp.next();
                       if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT){
                           String text = xpp.getName(); 
                           str +=  "**TEXT: "+text;
                       }


                   }
                   else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG)
                   {
                       str += "nending tag: "+xpp.getName();
                   }
                   else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT)
                   {
                       str += "nvalue : "+xpp.getText();
                   }
                   eventType = xpp.next();
              }
               str += "nnXML parsing Ending......";

        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }

  }
```

**Below is what my XML file looks like:**
I'm trying to access one text string located in an aya at a time.

```
<quran>
<sura index="1" name="الفاتحة">
    <aya index="1" text="In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful."/>
    <aya index="2" text="[All] praise is [due] to Allah, Lord of the worlds -"/>
    <aya index="3" text="The Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful,"/>
    <aya index="4" text="Sovereign of the Day of Recompense."/>
    <aya index="5" text="It is You we worship and You we ask for help."/>
    <aya index="6" text="Guide us to the straight path -"/>
    <aya index="7" text="The path of those upon whom You have bestowed favor, not of those who have evoked [Your] anger or of those who are astray."/>
</sura>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this correctly the problem here is that you have no value in your XML. You do however have some tags with attributes in them.

Ex:

```
<aya index="6" text="Guide us to the straight path -"/>
```

is not the same as:

```
<aya index="6">Guide us to the straight path -"</aya>
```

The later of these two would probably work with your code. What I think you want is to read the attribute `text` and not the value of the tag.

You will find further information on how to fetch the attributes [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html#START_TAG).

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're right in thinking that I need to read the **text attribute** for each aya but I need to do this in a search-like way. So for instance if a user enters 2:34 then that means this will return the string present in the second sura in text attribute of the aya with index attribute 34. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: Aha, now i get it. Check the index attribute for sura node, if it 2 search for index attribute for 25 of the aya node. I think it should be rather straight forward. You seem to have a good base to build from. Unless I missed something. :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, sorry been away for a while!