# Android: Read xml as a text

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing

There are some questions related but still not able to found the solution

I want to read file "myfile.xml" inside res/xml/and compare it with another text (String)

```
String compare = "this is just test";

try {
    Resources res = packageManager.getResourcesForApplication(packagename);
    int xml = res.getIdentifier("myxml", "xml", packagename);

    XmlResourceParser parser = res.getXml(appfilterxml);

    //How to read myxml.xml file and check it, like if myfile.xml contains String compare then ...

}
catch (NameNotFoundException e2) {
    e2.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried any tutorials?

Comment: Nope, just tried to search for question on stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read the xml file in `res/xml/myfile.xml`:

```
 InputStream object = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.xml.myfile);
```

That line will pen it, but to parse the xml and compare the contents to a string, you will need to look at an xml tutorial. There are numerous tutorials online.
Example:

http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/parsing-xml-from-the-sdcard-using-xmlpullparser/

http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/

There is one on this site as well: [Pull Parsing local XML File in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419540/pull-parsing-local-xml-file-in-android)

It's doubtful that you will find an example to suit you 100% so you will have to modify/change some parts of the code.